# Sharing Google Drive file for editing with people having no Google account

Tags: google-drive, sharing

I just created a file in Google Drive and made it "editable by anyone with the link". However, if I open the link in another browser where I'm not logged in Google, I seem unable to edit the file (I can see it though). Is it standard behaviour or have I made any mistake? An if it's standard, can I change it somehow so that all my collaborators (even those without Google account) can edit the file?

**This is the form for setting the permissions:**

[image]

**This is what I see in an other browser when I use the "Link to share" link** (click to enlarge)**:**

[image]

**The document when I open it in the other browser** (I didn't manage to make a screenshot of the File/Soubor menu, but all menu items like "Open" or "Edit" are disabled)**:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after seeing in the other answers that it really should work, I tried to trace the problem, here it goes:

**The file has to be a** - ***Google Spreadsheet*** - **rather than a** - ***XLS/XLSX Spreadsheet*** - **.**

The reason is that XLS(X) files need an additional App to be edited, which you can't use without Google account.

**How to know which is which?**  By the icon: [image] The left one is the good one (Google), the right one is the bad one (XLSX). Similar `W` is used for DOCX.

**How to convert the file?** Click *Open with... Google Sheets* and then *Save a copy*.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Are you sure your Sharing settings look like these?
I've just created a document and edited it without any troubles (created with my google account and edited using different browser - not logged in).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I see exactly the same thing as you with exactly the same settings. But then I'm unable to edit the document in another browser. I added screenshots to the question.

Comment: I got it. The reason is soooo stupid. See my self-answer, and thanks again for the help.

Comment: I see your file is of type xlsx (excel). You need you need to convert it to Google Docs format. see https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2407404?hl=en&rd=1

Comment: Yep, that's what I just made an answer about, including the reason.

Answer (score 1):

I think that, for editing, Google make a distinction between "anyone" - meaning a person with a Google account, and  "everyone" - meaning people irrespective of Google account status.

The distinction isn't applied to reading, but I'm sure I've send evidnece of it applying to edits before.

Comment: Thanks. Even changing to "Anyone on the web can edit" doesn't help. Do you have an idea how can I change it to "everyone"?

Comment: I got it. The reason is soooo stupid. See my self-answer, and thanks again for the help.